# jquery event handlers within a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I currently use javascript to create a html table.

When the user clicks on a button. It appends a `tr` to the table.

Inside the `tr` I also append a select2 `<select>` element.

The id of the `select` element is accompanied by a number that increments.

So the `select` element on the first row has an id of `item-project-no-0` and the element on the second row has an id of `item-project-no-1`. So on and so forth.

But now, I need to register the event listener for all the `select` elements in that table which is dynamically generated. Something like this:

```
    $('#item-project-no-' + x).on('select2:select', function (e) {

    });
```

I wanted to tried using a for loop. But I don't think the for loop knows how many times it must loop since the number of `select` elements is dependent on the number of timer user clicks a button.  I need to identify the individual select element that fires an event handle it accordingly.

I am open to all opinions and advice. Thanks.

Comment: Use event delegation instead, if at all possible. Creating separate IDs for every single element is a code smell.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just give each selector a class? Then you can do this:

```
$(document).on("select2:select", ".mySelectorClass", function() {
  // $(this) is the element
}
```

This works even for dynamically created elements later.

Comment: When I write `$(document).on("select2:select", ".myClass", function() {
  console.log("inside");
});` I realised that the  console will also log the string 'inside' when I am just creating the select element. I thought this event will only be fired when user make a selection using the select element ? Do you happen to know why ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
$(document).on("select2:select","[id^='item-project-no-']",function() {
  //do somthing
}
```